# Row collapse and expand according to json data in Table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html-table

Id like to expand the  row of the table td if it has child rows and also expand row-childrows as well if it has further sub child-row to the further it has now child-rows as Treeview Architecture.i want to show the data as in tree form as (Eg.Chart of Account )which has five root parent and its child,subchilds,sub-sub-child-Rows.what i am missing here ?

Tried as given in codesandbox. link to code Sandbox [https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-shadow-wsl8jm?file=/src/App.js:0-4385]